# ListView Web part - customization

Tags: 2010, web-part, development, visual-studio

I created and deployed link list (default template (103)) from code and after that I added ListViewWebPart also from code which looks on default view of my link list. And that works.

**Problem: How can i customize list from code so when i "load" that list in web part i get only reduced set of columns? For example (i want only "URL" column and not "Notes","Edit","Type" etc..  which i get default with "link list")**

I assume that i should create new view on list(but I don't know how i can create view and stick it on list - from code) and than load that new reduced view in webpart  **OR** somehow customize default view on web part. 
It's simple from designer, but any help how do that from code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this post on MSDN which involves programmatically creating list views: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/15/programmatically-create-a-view-custom-view-of-a-list-and-change-the-view.aspx